Room light controller
I just have learnt the command pattern carefully. I try to achieve the goal below in the right way. But I am sure the code may need some improvements.
Requirements:
Use the command pattern to create a naive operation manager that can execute a sequence of operations and undo the last three operations. (For a beginner player, you may skip the requirement that only undoes the last three operations; instead, you should undo all of the operations. For the advanced player, you are expected to restrict the manager to only undo the last three operations.)
Code:
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<memory>
#include<deque>
#include<string>

class Light
{
public:
    Light(std::string name):m_name(name){}

    void on()
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s light has been turned on just now" << std::endl;
    }

    void off()
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s light has been turned off just now" << std::endl;
    }

    void dim()
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s light has been dimmed just now" << std::endl;
    }

    void brighten()
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s light has been brightened up just now" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class ICommand
{
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual void unexecute() = 0;
    virtual ~ICommand() = default;
};

class LightOnCmd : public ICommand
{
public:
    LightOnCmd(std::shared_ptr<Light>  light_ptr):m_light_ptr(light_ptr){}

    void execute() override
    {
        m_light_ptr->on();
    }

    void unexecute() override
    {
        m_light_ptr->off();
    }

    ~LightOnCmd() override = default;
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Light> m_light_ptr;
};

class LightOffCmd : public ICommand
{
public:
    LightOffCmd(std::shared_ptr<Light>  light_ptr):m_light_ptr(light_ptr){}

    void execute() override
    {
        m_light_ptr->off();
    }

    void unexecute() override
    {
        m_light_ptr->on();
    }

    ~LightOffCmd() override = default;
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Light> m_light_ptr;
};

class LightDimCmd : public ICommand
{
public:
    LightDimCmd(std::shared_ptr<Light>  light_ptr):m_light_ptr(light_ptr){}

    void execute() override
    {
        m_light_ptr->dim();
    }

    void unexecute() override
    {
        m_light_ptr->brighten();
    }

    ~LightDimCmd() override = default;
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Light> m_light_ptr;
};

class LightBrightenCmd : public ICommand
{
public:
    LightBrightenCmd(std::shared_ptr<Light>  light_ptr):m_light_ptr(light_ptr){}

    void execute() override
    {
        m_light_ptr->brighten();
    }

    void unexecute() override
    {
        m_light_ptr->dim();
    }

    ~LightBrightenCmd() override = default;
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Light> m_light_ptr;
};

class LightInvoker
{
public:
    LightInvoker() = default;
    void execute(std::unique_ptr<ICommand> cmd)
    {
        cmd->execute();
        m_history.push_back(std::move(cmd));
    }

    void add_cmd(std::unique_ptr<ICommand> cmd)
    {
        m_to_run.push_back(std::move(cmd));
    }

    void execute_all_cmd()
    {
        for(auto& cmd : m_to_run)
        {
            cmd->execute();
            m_history.push_back(std::move(cmd));
        }

        decltype(m_to_run) empty;
        m_to_run.swap(empty);
    }

    void reverse_all()
    {
        while(!m_history.empty())
        {
            auto& cmd = m_history.back();
            cmd->unexecute();

            m_history.pop_back();
        }
    }

    void reverse_last_three()
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        while(!m_history.empty())
        {
            auto& cmd = m_history.back();
            cmd->unexecute();

            m_history.pop_back();

            if(++cnt == 3)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
private:
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>> m_history;
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>> m_to_run;
};


int main()
{
    auto bedroom_light_ptr = std::make_shared<Light>("bedroom");
    auto meetingroom_light_ptr = std::make_shared<Light>("meetingroom");

    LightInvoker invoker;

    invoker.execute(std::unique_ptr<ICommand>(new LightOnCmd(bedroom_light_ptr)));

    invoker.add_cmd(std::unique_ptr<ICommand>(new LightOnCmd(meetingroom_light_ptr)));
    invoker.add_cmd(std::unique_ptr<ICommand>(new LightDimCmd(meetingroom_light_ptr)));
    invoker.add_cmd(std::unique_ptr<ICommand>(new LightDimCmd(bedroom_light_ptr)));

    std::cout << "===to execute all the cmds set before" << std::endl;
    invoker.execute_all_cmd();
    invoker.execute_all_cmd();

    std::cout << "===to revise the last three ops" << std::endl;
    invoker.reverse_last_three();
    std::cout << "===to revise all the ops" << std::endl;
    invoker.reverse_all();
}


I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per site goals: "State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

I will follow your advice. :)

@John although it's great to know about it, that book is useless and some of the sub-patterns they mention (like "command pattern") are of no consequence. Sure, it's an (obvious) observation that a struct or whatever can contain "a command in some form" - and that's that.

@Fattie I am new to Design Pattern.  I just learnt Observer Pattern and Command Pattern. As far as I know they are different Patterns. I can't see any relation between them. For "it's an (obvious) observation that a struct or whatever can contain "a command in some form", could you please explain that in details for me?

Undoing is not the same as executing the opposite command
Deduplicator already mentioned this issue, but to clarify it with an example:
What if you execute LightOnCommand twice, and then just undo the last action? You would expect the light to stay on, but with your code the light will be off.
You don't need the command pattern in C++
The command pattern from the book Design Patterns is an object-oriented solution to a particular problem. However, C++ is not a pure object-oriented language, and allows you to solve the issue in different ways, in particular using a more functional programming style.
For example, you could use std::function to record actions. The main advantage is that you don't need to make a class hierarchy. If we forget about undo functionality for a moment, it could look like this:
class LightInvoker
{
public:
    void add_cmd(std::function<void()> cmd) {
        m_to_run.push_back(std::move(cmd));
    }

    void execute_all_cmd() {
        for (auto& cmd: m_to_run)
            cmd();
        m_to_run.clear();
    }
    …
private:
    std::deque<std::function<void()>> m_to_run;
};

int main()
{
    auto bedroom_light = Light("bedroom");
    LightInvoker invoker;
    …
    invoker.add_cmd([&]{ bedroom_light.on(); });
    invoker.add_cmd([&]{ bedroom_light.dim(); });
    invoker.add_cmd([&]{ bedroom_light.dim(); });

    invoker.execute_all_cmd();
    …
}

Note how we don't need to create a class ICommand, nor any of the classes deriving from it. This decoupling makes everything much more flexible.
To add undo functionality, you could have each command return another std::function that contains the command to undo the action. Here is an example of how that might work:
class LightInvoker
{
public:
    using UndoCommand = std::function<void()>;
    using Command = std::function<UndoCommand()>;

    void add_cmd(Command cmd) {
        m_to_run.push_back(std::move(cmd));
    }

    void execute_all_cmd() {
        for (auto& cmd: m_to_run)
            m_history.push_front(cmd());
        m_to_run.clear();
    }

    void reverse_all()
    {
        for (auto& undo_cmd: m_history)
            undo_cmd();
        m_history.clear();
    }
    …
private:
    std::deque<Command> m_to_run;
    std::deque<UndoCommand> m_history;
};

auto light_on_command(Light& light) {
    return [&light] -> LightInvoker::UndoCommand {
        if (light.is_on()) {
            // It is already on, nothing to do or undo
            return []{};
        } else {
            light.on();
            return [&]{ light.off(); };
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto bedroom_light = Light("bedroom");
    LightInvoker invoker;
    …
    invoker.add_cmd(light_on_command(bedroom_light));
    …
}

Note that I didn't use std::shared_ptrs here for simplicity, but you can still use those. Also, it's not wrong to use the command pattern, this is just to illustrate that there are alternative ways in C++.

How to understand [&]{ bedroom_light.on(); } in the right way? In paticular, why there is a ';' in the {} and there is [&] other than &. I can understand std::bind(&Light::on, bedroom_light); while I really have never seen the aforementioned expression before.

@John [&]{ bedroom_light.on(); } is a lambda expression, which essentially passes the bedroom_light.on() function anonymously as an object.  The [&] is a capture clause, which controls the visibility of variables within the body of the lambda.  See here for more.

I see, thank you so much! I remember it now.

I do little modification with your code snippet to avoid the command is executed at once.

Note that you can still use std::bind() instead of lambda expressions with std::function.


When you want to support undoing (and redoing) commands, you have basically these options:

Save only the commands. This is simple and saves space, but undoing a command means plaing back all commands from the initial state, which is costly.
Save a delta. Slightly more complicated, needs a bit more space, but undoing a command is simple and efficient.
Save snapshots. It costs loads of memory, but is very simple.
Use immutable shared state. Reduces the cost of snapshots to that of deltas, but pervades the whole program.

Currently, you are using 1 but trying to backtrack as if you had 2, which does not work.

Avoid std::endl. Instead, use '\n' directly, and add std::flush only if you really truly mean it. Thus, you are concise and efficient for the common case, and explicit for the rare one where you need something surprising.

You can copy std::string and std::shared_ptr, but moving them is much more efficient. Use the right one.



Thanks a lot to @G. Sliepen, @Deduplicator.
For the reader who reads this post in the future. I do little modification which is detailed explained in the comment for G. Sliepen's inplementaion.
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Light
{
public:
    Light(std::string name):m_name(name), m_state{LightState::OFF}{}

    void on()
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s light has been turned on just now" << std::endl;
        m_state = LightState::ON;
    }

    void off()
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s light has been turned off just now" << std::endl;
        m_state = LightState::OFF;
    }

    void dim()
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s light has been dimmed just now" << std::endl;
    }

    void brighten()
    {
        std::cout << m_name << "'s light has been brightened up just now" << std::endl;
    }

    bool is_on()
    {
        return m_state == LightState::ON;
    }
private:
    enum class LightState : unsigned char
    {
        ON,
        OFF
    };

    std::string m_name;
    LightState m_state;
};

class LightInvoker
{
public:
    using UndoCmdFunc = std::function<void()>;
    using CmdFunc = std::function<UndoCmdFunc()>;

    void add_cmd(CmdFunc cmd) {
        if(cmd)
        {
            m_to_run.push_back(std::move(cmd));
        }
    }

    void execute_all_cmd() {
        for (auto& cmd: m_to_run)
        {
            if(cmd)
            {
                auto undo = cmd();
                if(undo)
                {
                   m_history.push_front(std::move(undo));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void reverse_all_cmd() {
        for(auto& func : m_history)
        {
            if(func)
            {
                func();
            }
        }

        m_history.clear();
    }

private:
    std::deque<CmdFunc> m_to_run;
    std::deque<UndoCmdFunc> m_history;
};

int main()
{
    auto bedroom_light = std::make_shared<Light>(Light("bedroom"));
    auto meetingroom_light = std::make_shared<Light>(Light("meetingroom_light"));

    auto turn_on_light = [](std::shared_ptr<Light> light_ptr)->std::function<void()>{

        if(!light_ptr)
        {
            return {};
        }

        if(light_ptr->is_on())
        {
            return {};
        }

        light_ptr->on();

        return [=]{light_ptr->off();};  //should use = other than &, since share_ptr is captured
    };

    auto turn_off_light = [](std::shared_ptr<Light> light_ptr)->std::function<void()>{
        if(!light_ptr)
        {
            return {};
        }

        if(!light_ptr->is_on())
        {
            return {};
        }

        light_ptr->off();

        return [=]{light_ptr->on();};  //should use = other than &, since share_ptr is captured
    };

    LightInvoker invoker;

    invoker.add_cmd(std::bind(turn_on_light, bedroom_light));  //turn_on_light(bedroom_light) causes the cmd is executed at once.
    invoker.add_cmd(std::bind(turn_on_light, bedroom_light));
    invoker.add_cmd(std::bind(turn_on_light, meetingroom_light));

    std::cout << "===to execute all the cmds" << "\n";
    invoker.execute_all_cmd();

    std::cout << "===to reverse all the cmds" << "\n";
    invoker.reverse_all_cmd();
}


I think there is a problem with if (undo) { m_history.push_front(std::move(undo)); }: how does the history now distinguish between not having an action been done at all versus an empty action? I would make it so that in execute_all_cmd(), for every entry that was in m_to_run, whether it was an empty std::function or not, you push an entry into m_history.

1. If I understand you correctly, you mean void execute_all_cmd() { for (auto& cmd: m_to_run) {  if(cmd)  {  m_history.push_front(cmd()); }}}, right?  2. I think an action been done at all eqauls to empty action since no real request would be invoked and no state would be modified. If I missed sth, please let me know. @G.Sliepen
